# What does unique_ptr<T>::operator= do in terms of deallocation

Tags: c++11

I'm having troubles understanding fully the assignment operator for unique_ptr. I understand that we can only move them, due to the fact that copy constructor and assignment operators are deleted, but what if 
a unique_ptr which contains already an allocation is overwritten by a move operation? Is the content previously stored in the smart pointer free'd?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A{
public:
    A() = default;
    virtual void act() const {
        std::cout << "act from A" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~A() {
        std::cout << "destroyed A" << std::endl;
    }
};
class B : public A {
public:
    B() : A{} {}
    void act() const override {
        std::cout << "act from B" << std::endl;
    }

    ~B() override {
        std::cout << "destroyed from B " << std::endl;
    }
};
int main() {
    auto pP{std::make_unique<A>()};
    pP->act();

    ==================== ! =======================
    pP = std::make_unique<B>(); // || std::move(std::make_unique<B>())
    ==================== ! =======================

    pP->act();
    return 0;
}
```

When I do

```
pP = std::make_unique<B>();
```

does it mean that what was allocated in the first lines for pP (new A()) is destructed automatically? 
Or should I opt for:

```
pP.reset();
pP = std::make_unique<B>();
```

Comment: what have you got in output? do you see that the first instance was destroyed? did this answer your question?

Comment: Considering it was a polymorphic call I had "act from A" "destroyed from A", the next part is obvious. But I needed some clarification, even tho I did debug the code in order to see the internals of unique_ptr.

Comment: @AndriyTylychko Trying something out and seeing what happens doesn't tell you anything about what's supposed to happen or is guaranteed to happen.

Comment: @Cubic: let's be realistic and not pedantic. OP asks about very basic C++ staff and if any C++ compiler behaves not according to C++ standard in such basic cases it's literally dead and not worth to be mentioned. I was trying to understand the root of OP's confusion to potentially show the way how to avoid it in the future.

Comment: @AndriyTylychko How is a beginner going to tell the difference between "basic" stuff and stuff that's not basic? There are a lot of situations that are unspecified or undefined that seem perfectly reasonable to many beginners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see section 20.9.1, paragraph 4 of the [C++11 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf)

> Additionally, u can, upon request, transfer ownership to another unique pointer u2. Upon completion of
>   such a transfer, the following postconditions hold:
>
> - u2.p is equal to the pre-transfer u.p,
> - u.p is equal to nullptr, and
> - if the pre-transfer u.d maintained state, such state has been transferred to u2.d.
>
> As in the case of a reset, **u2 must properly dispose of its pre-transfer owned object via the pre-transfer
>   associated deleter before the ownership transfer is considered complete**

In other words, it's cleaning up after itself upon assignment like you'd expect.

Comment: Thank you, I'm following other books in which such thing was not specified, too bad.

Comment: @AlexNyken The C++ standard is quite verbose by necessity, it's not surprising that teaching books won't spell out everything it says. The authors of your book probably didn't think it was necessary to mention at the time or might've even thought it was obvious (or otherwise, they might've mentioned it as an offhand remark that you missed).

Comment: Most definitely

Answer (score 1):

Yes, replacing the content of a smart pointer will release the previously-held resource.  You do not need to call `reset()` explicitly (nor would anyone expect you to).

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of this particular example. It seems polymorphism in your example didn't allow you to draw clear conclusions from output:

```
act from A
destroyed A
act from B
destroyed from B 
destroyed A
```

So let's simplify your example and make it straight to the point:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A {
    explicit A(int id): id_(id)
    {}

    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "destroyed " << id_ << std::endl;
    }

    int id_;
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<A> pP{std::make_unique<A>(1)};
    pP = std::make_unique<A>(2);
}
```

which outputs:

```
destroyed 1
destroyed 2
```

[Online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6BoEZqd0g4gd8SbZ)

I hope this leaves no room for misinterpretation.